# Avoid defaulting to deny when a site has multiple headers for X-Frame-Options

Tags: same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

When there are multiple `X-Frame-Options` defined, can you avoid falling back to `DENY`?

The error shown:

`Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN') encountered when loading 'https://example.com'. Falling back to 'DENY'.`

Answer (score 1):

In case of **nginx**, yes you can, by using `nginx-extras`.

1. `sudo apt-get install nginx-extras`

Now if you don't know find out where your nginx config file is by running `sudo nginx -t` (possibly it includes other config files) and adjust next path as needed:

2. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconfig` or whatever editor you use.

In the `server { ... }`, add the line `more_set_headers 'X-Frame-Options:';` if you want to remove all values from the header, or specify

3. `more_set_headers 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN';` if you want that one instead. This will replace (overrule) any other header settings.
4. `sudo service nginx restart`